# htaccess working locally but not working on life servers

Tags: php, .htaccess

I tried .htaccess on my local server (localhost) and it's working well.

But when upload this code to life server not working ... i don't know why ?!!

This is the content of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^home/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    home.php?country=$1&name=$2&listingId=$3    [NC,L]
```

the expected that url work ... it's work on localhost only ... but on live server it's give me 404 notFound

MY-DOMAIN.COM/home/USA/David/1234

My live server is www.000webhost.com

Comment: What does "not working" mean exactly? There are many ways in which this could be "not working".

Comment: do you have access to the web server config? if so, please post it here..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to follow the advice given by your hoster and put `RewriteBase /` at the top of the .htaccess file?

see http://www.000webhost.com/faq.php?ID=16